# Is my closet wall bearing a load

Tags: structural

I had a contractor come in for a closet and bathroom remodel. He took down a wall to make the closet bigger. His work was so bad now I’m not sure if the wall he removed is load bearing.[image]

Comment: The back wall of the closet might be load bearing, maybe.  We can't tell without knowing more about how the house is built.  We need to know the way the joists go and where the support beams are.  Hint, walls above support beams are usually load bearing.

Comment: If that 2x4 hanging down (with the wire going through it) is all that was up there, I would presume it wasn't a "load bearing" wall.